# Efficiency of JSP calling functions directly

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, glassfish

Is it a good idea to have a JSP page call my java classes directly or is it better to do an http post to my web service? what is the difference in terms of scalability and security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP has its own responsibility, view generation. Unless required, it doesn't make sense to embed any java code inside JSP. Invoked Servlet/Other framework controller to do business logic.

If the calls are with-in same web application, let us say from JSP1 to JSP2 (or) JSP1 to Servlet2, webservices calls doesn't make sense. They will be heavy.

Answer (score 1):

JSP-Files are used to generate Servlets. So JSP-Files and Servlets are mostly the same. There is no difference for security or scalability.